# SQL - Add value with previous row only

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I have a table named myvals with the following fields:

```
ID   number
--   -------
1     7
2     3
3     4
4     0
5     9
```

Starting on 2nd row, I would like to add the number with the previous row number.  So, my end result would look like this

```
ID   number
--   ------
1      7
2     10
3      7
4      4
5      9
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use the [LAG](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh231256.aspx) analytic function

```
SELECT Id, number + LAG(number,1,0) OVER (ORDER BY Id) FROM table
```

Comment: ahhh right, thanks xxMUROxx!  forgot about the LAG function in 2012.  it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

First thing's first. You can't add to null to ID 1 must have a value.

Comment: Hi ArtK, the ID column is an identity column in my case.

Answer (score -1):

```
create table #temp
(
    month_type datetime,
    value int


)
insert into #temp
Select '2015/01/01',1
union
Select '2015/02/01',2
union
Select '2015/03/01',3
union
Select '2015/04/01',4



SELECT t.value,t1.value,(t.value+t1.value)/2 FROM #temp t1
left join #temp t on t.month_type=Dateadd(MONTH,-1,t1.month_type)
```

Comment: Thanks for posting an answer to this question!  Code-only answers [are discouraged](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/148274) on Stack Overflow, because a code dump with no context doesn't explain how or why the solution will work, making it impossible for the original poster (or any future readers) to understand the logic behind it.  Please, edit your question and include an explanation of your code so that others can benefit from your answer.

Comment: In addition, it is very helpful if you properly [format your code blocks](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks) - I've done it for you here, but it really does help make your answer more readable!  Best of luck, and welcome to Stack Overflow!